# Transparent UINavigationBar in UITableViewController in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have view controllers where I set the navigation bar to be transparent like this:

```
viewController.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
[viewController.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

For my `UIViewController` this works fine and I am able to get this:

[image]

However, when I am using a `UITableViewController` it doesn't quite work and I get this:

[image]

It't the grey background in the navigation bar that I can't get rid of. I am experiencing this issue in iOS 8.3. I have tested it in iOS 7.1 and there it works fine.

**EDIT:**

I have tried setting the following without success:

```
tableViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
tableViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it:

1 . You can override the Navigation Controller class and in the viewDidLoad method of your view controllor just specify this code to change the color of UINavigationBar .

---

```
self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.blue //   you can give color of your choice
self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // or UIColor clearColor
```

2.If you want to do it universally or want to apply the same color of navigation bar throughout the app then use this below code in `AppDelegate's` `:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  method:

---

```
UINavigationBar.appearance() .barTintColor = UIColor(red: 100.0/255.0, green: 226.0/255.0, blue: 98.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)  // you can give color of your choice
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // or UIColor clearColor
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Vizlix. However, setting the tint color and text color is not my issue her (they are in fact set using `UIAppearance`). My problem is that making the navigation bar transparent using this common method doesn't quite work in `UITableViewController` in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to also set `shadowImage` and the background color to clear. I use the following and it works fine for iOS7 and iOS8 on all controllers.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0f){
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}
else{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Hi Rory. Thank your for the suggestion. I have actually already tried setting the `shadowInmage` without any luck. I have updated my question with that I have tried. I hoped that `self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` would do the trick, but sadly it didn't.

Comment: Try setting the Navigation Bar style on the UINavigationController to Black.You might want to set the barTint to clear as well.